# passing variables

Tags: objective-c, variables, implementation, sharing

Ok here is an example of what I'm dealing with at the moment:

```
@implementation ECHOAppDelegate
 ...
 @end

 @interface PtyView (PtyPrivate)
 -(void)startTask;
 -(void) didRead: (NSNotification *)fileNoty;
 @end

 @implementation PtyView
 ...
 -(void)startTask {
 //starts task
 }
 @end
```

Now, if I wanted to "trigger" `startTask` from the ECHOAppDelegate implementation, how would I do that? Now, it says that it wasn't declared.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure you import the `PtyView` header. In `ECHOAppDelegate.m`:

```
#import "PtyView.h"
```

Then, assuming you have an instance of `PtyView`:

```
[myPtyViewObj startTask];
```

Comment: Ok thanks! but for some reason I'm getting this error: 'PtyView' may not respond to '-startTask' Here is the code I'm using:  PtyView *ptyviewobject = [[PtyView alloc] init];
 [ptyviewobject startTask];